# Representing the arc of a circumference in Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-views

So, my goal here, is to calculate the measurement of the arc, and here goes my question. How do I represent that in HTML using Django?

```
def PartOfCircumference(angle):
radius = 5
circumference = math.pi * radius * 2
part_of_circumference = angle / 360
measurement = float(circumference * part_of_circumference)
return measurement
```

Comment: What do you mean with "represent that in HTML"?

Comment: It would be to put that part of a circumference in a template, so the user can visualize it